# Willdfly server log is not printing the log information after running for a week

Tags: logging, wildfly-10

I'm running wildfly 10 and log information is printing in server.log but from last week I've noticed that log is not printing and it shows last week date(last modified date). please guide me to solve the issue.

Note: After restarting the server it was working fine but need to know the reason why it is not printing log information.

Comment: That sounds environmental. What platform is WildFly running on?

Comment: i'm running  wildfly in Ubuntu environment. this issue happened suddenly but application was working fine (log alone not writing to the file)

Comment: I would make check up standard out then. Maybe there was some kind of issue/error writing to the log file.